# Does Heroku support side-by-side application deployment?

Tags: deployment, heroku

I'm trying to learn about Heroku's deployment capabilities.  I've used Google App Engine in the past and have found its support for multiple simultaneously-accessible live application versions useful, for example, in order to test a new version in the production context before making it the default, running a specially-instrumented version in parallel with the default version to debug a problem specific to the production environment (e.g. production data), for A/B testing, traffic splitting, gradual rollout, etc.

Does Heroku have support for this kind of thing?  My Googling has not turned up anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't offer support for this right now.